# Python to exe: py2exe issues with pkg_resources

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I've built an application in Python that I'd like to distribute to my enterprise and installing Python on each machine is unfortunately not an option. I'd like to convert the application to an .exe so that users can run my application with shortcut on their desktop.

This is my first attempt at distribution, so please forgive my lack of knowledge on the subject. I'm having issues with py2exe when I attempt to convert my .py script to a .exe.

My setup.py script looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import numpy
import matplotlib

setup(console=['inpho.py'],
      data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles()
      )
```

After I run `python setup.py py2exe`, I get the expected `dist` and `build` directories. However, if I run my application, now called `InPho.exe`, a cmd window opens and I immediately get an error: `ImportError: No module named pkg_resources`.

My first thought is that my setup.py script is wrong, I just do not know how to properly write one. In my inpho.py script, I use import the following:

- pandas
- Tkinter
- pyodbc
- sqlalchemy
- sqlite3
- datetime
- tkMessageBox
- os
- shutil

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Py2exe might not handle some of the dependencies out of the box. Try this advice from the py2exe tutorial on how to handle import errors in this case: [Dealing With ImportError](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/DealingWithImportError)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'm reading through this documentation now. Any other advice is still happily welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar issues with py2exe.  I was able to fix them by downgrading setuptools to version 19.2.

You can see more information about this setuptools issue here: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1781