# Simple py2exe breaks with numpy import

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, py2exe

I have a wxPython GUI, and I've been using py2exe to package it as a frozen binary for Windows.  I was able to use this successfully a month or two ago, but now everything is breaking.

Here is very simple example file that is failing:

```
import sys
import wx

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(redirect=True)
    app.frame = wx.Frame(None, title="My frame")
    app.frame.Center()
    app.frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I'm using the actual setup file from my real project, so it includes:

```
options = {
    "py2exe": {
        "includes": ["scipy", "scipy.special.*", "scipy.linalg.*", "scipy.linalg.__decomp_update", "scipy.sparse.*", "scipy.sparse.csgraph.*", "scipy.ndimage", "scipy.ndimage.*", scipy.linalg.cython_blas"],
        "packages": ["matplotlib", "pytz", "pandas"],
        "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll", ...]
        },
    ...
    }
```

When I try to make a new build, I get an error that says "no such file or directory 'numpy-atlas.dll'".

If I add "numpy-atlas.dll" to the "dll_excludes" list, the build runs, but the executable doesn't run.  I get this error in the log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "magic_gui.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 122, in <module>
  File "matplotlib\cbook.pyc", line 33, in <module>
  File "numpy\__init__.pyc", line 180, in <module>
  File "numpy\add_newdocs.pyc", line 13, in <module>
  File "numpy\lib\__init__.pyc", line 8, in <module>
  File "numpy\lib\type_check.pyc", line 11, in <module>
  File "numpy\core\__init__.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "numpy\core\multiarray.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "numpy\core\multiarray.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

This similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942210/python-to-exe-py2exe-issues-with-pkg-resources) led me to this [documentation](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ExeWithEggs) about using py2exe with eggs.  I don't think any of my dependencies are in egg form, though.

I'm particularly puzzled because this very same setup file worked just fine until very recently.

UPDATE:

I eventually solved this problem before I got around to posting the question.  I added "numpy-atlas.dll" to the "ignore_dlls" list, but then manually added it into my distribution folder.  Obviously that isn't a very satisfactory solution, so if someone can suggest a better solution/explanation, that would be great.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried packaging this with cx_freeze?

Comment: I haven't.  I tried Pyinstaller and dead-ended there (doesn't play nice with Enthought Python).  Given the amount of time I invested in getting everything up and running with py2exe, I don't really want to invest that much time in another system.